# Angular , Phantomjs - finished rendering page

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs

I would like to test if all partial and all request has been done and then craw page with Phantomjs. How can I get information that all request (ajax, loading partials) are finished.

Comment: Did you check http://prerender.io/?

Answer (score 0):

There's no event for that because things are dependent on your server.

IMHO the best way to handle this is to create a flag for when you decide the loading has been done.

Comment: Yes, I guess that's how prerender.io does it (`window.prerenderReady = false;`): http://prerender.io/getting-started#wait-for-render